# Dynamically update date picker options

Tags: datepicker

I am using the following code to select multiple dates from the date picker:

```
 jQuery("#m_dates")
        .datepicker({
          onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
              $scope.addOrRemoveDate(dateText,$scope.multi_dates,'m');
          },
          beforeShowDay: function (date) { 
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var month = $scope.padNumber(date.getMonth() + 1);
            var day = $scope.padNumber(date.getDate());
            // This depends on the datepicker's date format
            var dateString = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
            var gotDate = jQuery.inArray(dateString, $scope.data.post.multi_dates);

            if (gotDate >= 0) {
             // Enable date so it can be deselected. Set style to be highlighted
                return [true, "state-highlight"];
            }

            // Dates not in the array are left enabled, but with no extra style
               return [true, ""];
          },
          changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate: jQuery.datepicker.parseDate($scope.data.post.date_format,$scope.data.post.start_date),
                maxDate: jQuery.datepicker.parseDate($scope.data.post.date_format,$scope.data.post.end_date)
          });
```

On changing the Start and End Date fields, I want to change minDate and maxDate options for the above date picker. For that I have used the following code:

```
    jQuery('#m_dates').datepicker("change", { 
           minDate: jQuery.datepicker.parseDate($scope.data.post.date_format,$scope.data.post.start_date) 
          });
    jQuery('#m_dates').datepicker('change', { 
           maxDate: jQuery.datepicker.parseDate($scope.data.post.date_format,$scope.data.post.end_date) 
          });
    jQuery('#m_dates').datepicker("refresh");
```

But the code above refreshes the calendar dates only if I click on date picker.

Comment: have you tried to trigger `$(this).change();` inside `OnSelect` method?

Comment: tried without any success.

Comment: is your change method at least being called?